# Loop produced by .htaccess gives message ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm playing around with .htaccess to have more clean URLs. My .htaccess is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule SmartMenu SmartMenuPrototype/dashboard [NC,L]
```

The browser gives me the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS message. And in the apache2 error log file I get this message:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. etc..
```

I suppose I'm creating a loop somehow, but I'm new to the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use anchors in your regex:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^SmartMenu/?$ SmartMenuPrototype/dashboard [NC,L]
```

Otherwise `SmartMenu` will also match `SmartMenuPrototype`.